# Why is my Objective-C object being deallocated after viewDidLoad: is called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, lifecycle

The object created deallocated after viewDidLoad: method in Cocoa

Please see the code below:

```
#import "ShowTableViewController.h"

@interface ShowTableViewController ()

@property NSArray *data;

@end

@implementation ShowTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.data = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"];
    NSLog(@"%ld",self.data.count);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",self.data.count);
    return self.data.count;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return self.data[row];
}

@end
```

**The output is** 
3 
0

I checked the execution order using breakpoints viewDidLoad is called first!
I resolved it by using `awakeFromNib` method. but i want to know why this is happening
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you want here ?

Comment: Try  `self.data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];`

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: His concern is that count of `self.data` is logged 3 in viewDidLoad but logged as 0 in numberOfRowsInTableView.

Comment: How do you know that the data was actually deallocated? As has been noted, you did not call reloaddata

Comment: Even after using reloadData the output is same. moreover I printed the object it was nil

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload your `tableView` in `viewDidLoad` after assigning your array like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.data = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"%ld",self.data.count);
}
```

This have solved my problem, hope it will solve your too.

Comment: He did not have the object in the array inside `tableViewDataSource` method.

Comment: My problem is the object created in viewDidLoad gets deallocated in table view data source method... I don't know how that's possible. Are u facing the same situation as well

Comment: My problem was that i am not reloading the tableView just like you after assigning array in `viewDidLoad`. After `reloadData` it is working fine. Have you try that?

Comment: Even after using reloadData the output is same. moreover I printed the object it was null

Comment: @ArunEA Currently i don't have `Xcode` i will give you reply about this tomorrow.

Comment: I found out the bug.. Its really stupid. Its a honest mistake on my part. I created another object of this view controller in interface builder so there were two objects this whole time.

Answer (score 0):

I had to objects in total. One in the interface builder and another one created by me in code. the object was not getting deallocated. the second object was assigned as the datasource, so it was returning zero. Its a honest mistake on my part. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks you all for the answers :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to declare your data property as strong

@property NSArray *data;

becomes

@property (strong) NSArray *data;

Comment: The `strong` attribute is the default for objects.